# How to make sure a JavaScript function not to execute until other ajax promises are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I have a couple of JavaScript functions that call ajax promises to populate fields. Like this:

```
var functionA = function () {
   //Prepare data for ajax service call
   service.getDataA()
      .then((data) => $("#inputA").val(data));
}
var functionB = function () {
   //Prepare data for ajax service call
   service.getDataB()
      .then((data) => $("#inputB").val(data));
}
```

Here are the ajax

```
var getDataA  = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: data,
    });
};

var getDataB  = function () {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: `url,
        data: data,
    });
};
```

So far, so good.

The issue is, I have a third function, functionC, that depends on the completion of functionA and functionB. I need functionC to execute when both functionA and functionB are complete. I have tried several ways to try to achieve this, with no success.

How do I accomplish something like this?

```
When functionA and functionB are done
.Then functionC.
```

Comment: Use Promise.all

Comment: [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) if you want a JS native solution, or [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) if you prefer still using jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Promise.all, example:

```
var functionA = function () {
   return service.getDataA()
      .then((data) => $("#inputA").val(data));
}

var functionB = function () {
   return service.getDataB()
      .then((data) => $("#inputB").val(data));
}

var functionC = function () {
    // functionC logic here
}

Promise.all([functionA(), functionB()])
    .then(functionC)
    .catch((err) => {
        // Handle error
        console.error(err);
    });
```

Comment: Wrong !!! You are not creating promises on each function

Comment: Not sure why this answer is wrong? This answer is the one that achieves what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

As Daniel has said in the comments. `Promise.all` is the best solution. If you cannot use it for some reason, a pattern that could work is the following:

```js
// some globally-accessible state
const returnStates = {
  hasA: false,
  hasB: false,
  hasC: false,
};

const tryC = () => {
  if (!returnStates.hasA || !returnStates.hasB) return

  service.getDataC();

  returnStates.hasC = true;
};

getDataA.then(() => {
  returnStates.hasA = true;

  tryC();
});

getDataB.then(() => {
  returnStates.hasB = true;

  tryC();
});
```

You can adapt this to contain `returnStates` differently, wrap it in `tryC`, or use a global state management tool. This mimics `redux-thunk` essentially without the redux or the thunk.

Answer (score 0):

Promise.all() is the guy, something like this:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  //your Function1
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  //your Function2
});


Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
   .then(res => {
    //your Function3
})
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: no need to wrap the existing jquery.ajax in a `new Promise`, since jquery.ajax already returns a thenable

Comment: then if we move to pure jquery we can use when(Func1,Func2).then(Func3), honestly i prefer to wrap in new promises but is up to the developer taste. do you agree?

Comment: yes and no. Since $.ajax (at least after some early 1.x jquery) returns a perfectly usable thenable (i.e. it works with so-called native Promises), there's hardly ever any need to wrap the returned (from $.ajax) object in a new Promise - and if you do want to do that, you'd just `return Promise.resolve($.ajax(....))` anyway